# Where to find header esd.h

Tags: compilation, sdl, alsa

I'm trying to compile libSDL from source and I'm getting the following error:

```
./src/audio/esd/SDL_esdaudio.c:30:17: fatal error: esd.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [build/SDL_esdaudio.lo] Error 1
```

After a quick search I'm still a little confused about where to pick up the header (and presumably the corresponding library). I see there is the EsounD package, ALSA, and AudioFile.

What is the minimum requirement to get this working? I have to compile everything from scratch so I don't want to have more than I need.

Comment: Look at the libraries required at the bottom of the page: http://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQLinux or you can check the README.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like it requires EsoundD and ALSA directly. However, EsounD requires AudioFile (which requires ALSA, too).

In short, it requires all three.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was sufficient to install `libesd0-dev`
see https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libesd0-dev/filelist